# Looking for an easier way to select a (part of) Column (not EntireColumn) within a Range worksheet.("upperleftmostPointByName").CurrentRegion

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection

I'm looking for an easy way to select the columns within a given Range.

The Sub below does this, but it seems to be too complicated...

Somebody an idea?

```
Sub selectColumnInCurrentRegion(columnNrToBeSelected as Integer)
    
    Dim myRange  As Range
    Dim myArr As Variant 'just for debugging purposes
    
    Dim myWS As Worksheet
    Set myWS = ws_TargetForCGraphSearch 'Adjust your Worksheet
    
    Dim upperLeftCornerAsName As String
    upperLeftCornerAsName = "TargetResultStartPoint" 'Adjust your Corner
    
    Set myRange = Application.Intersect(myWS.Range(upperLeftCornerAsName).CurrentRegion, _                                                                
                  myWS.Range(upperLeftCornerAsName).Offset(0, columnNrToBeSelected -1).EntireColumn)
    myArr = myRange
    
    myRange.Select

 End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the columns property to access column of choice from CurrentRegion range object.

```
Set myRange = myWS.Range(upperLeftCornerAsName).CurrentRegion.Columns(columnNrToBeSelected)
```

Belts and braces, you would check `myWS.Range(upperLeftCornerAsName).CurrentRegion` is valid and the `columnNrToBeSelected is <= .columns.Count` of `.CurrentRegion` and `>0`.

Comment: That simple.....I tried something with that property before, but I did it obviously wrong ....it selected only one cell.... but now it works, thank you very much!

Comment: ...Now I know what the problem was.... I tried it in the way you proposed earlier, I found it and and it failed again "sometimes"...

I have an own  "windowclass" which opens a second Window for Debug Output. This happens at the same time I want to select the column.... the opening of the window and the selection are time critical at the same time.......

Comment: Is this something you can reliably reproduce and open as a new question with an example we can also reproduce please?

Comment: I can reproduce it, yes, but I think that there is not much you can do, if the focus is left, excel can not select the cells, the object ist lost. I think I can close this topic here.  I will investigate it further until it is stabil reproducable and worth it to create a new question, thank you for your help!